# Can ASP.Net web application be uploaded to server

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.Net web application. I want to publish it to the Windows host. But I am not sure if I can do this. When I try to publish a **Web Site** it is ok but a **Web Application** ?

If I can not, is there a way to turn the web application to a web site in Visual Studio. Because when I try to copy the files of ASP.Net web application into an ASP.Net web site I get too many errors that I dont understand half.

Thanks for any respose.

Comment: yes you can publish web application to webserver, can you post errors you are getting?

Comment: when I try to publish it asks the target location, it is the address of the website ? like, http://www.asdasdasd.com. and then it says;
Unable to create the Web site 'http://www.asdasdas.com'.  The Web server does not appear to have FrontPage Server Extensions installed.
========== Build: 3 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: check reply below from henson, publish it to local folder, connect via ftp and copy files to web folder,  it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right click the web application in visual studio -> click publish -> follow the gui ( I usually just publish it to a folder on my desktop). Then, you simply upload the files in generated directory to the site root of your hosting site. You can usually just do this via the ftp site that the hosting company gives you. You do want to make sure that the hosting site has the correct version of .NET installed and enabled for the application pool you are using. That is usually all there is to it.

If you receive errors about missing dependencies, you will have to take that up with the provider.

Comment: " The Web server does not appear to have FrontPage Server Extensions installed. " says the error.

Comment: @Mustafa Are you using FrontPage? If not, use the method I listed, and ignore the error. If you are, you need to talk to the hosting company and have them fix it.

Comment: it is ok! after publishing it to local, then upload with ftp, it is working thank you.